# Repetitions required to choose from a list

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Say I have a list of $n$ objects and I randomly choose one item from the list, but did not remove it. What is the method for calculating the probability I have chosen $x$ different items in the list after $n$ attempts?

For example, I am randomly choosing a number between $1$ and $100$. After how many attempts will I have had a $90\%$ chance that I chose $10$ distinct numbers?

Is there a specific name for this type of probability?

Comment: "with replacement" as opposed to "without replacement". Do you see why the answer is at least 10?

Comment: specific name for this type of *probability* or this type of *problem* ? For the latter, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem